# How get attribute content by another attribute value with XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

I have XML like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
                  xmlns='urn:hl7-org:v3'
                  xmlns:ext='urn:hl7-RU-EHR:v1'
                  xsi:schemaLocation='urn:hl7-org:v3'>
    <author>
        <time value='20160809000000+0300'/>
        <assignedAuthor>
            <id root='1.2.643.5.1.13.3.25.1.1.100.1.1.70' extension='1'/>
            <id root='1.2.643.100.3' extension='03480134121'/>
            <id nullFlavor='NI'/>
        </assignedAuthor>
    </author>
</ClinicalDocument>
```

I have to get `extension` in `id` with `root`'s value = `1.2.643.100.3`.
I must use XPath 2.0.
I have tried:

1. `*[name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[name()='author']/*[name()='assignedAuthor']/*[name()='id' and @id='1.2.643.100.3']/@extension`. Not working
2. `/*[name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[name()='author']/*[name()='assignedAuthor']/*[name()='id'][2]/@extension`, but order of `id`s can 
   mixed. So that, I should retrieve by `id`'s value

It's needed to me for retrieving value by Java's XPathExpression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct XPath: `/*[name()='ClinicalDocument']/*[name()='author']/*[name()='assignedAuthor']/*[local-name()='id' and @root='1.2.643.100.3']/@extension`

Answer (score 1):

First, bind namespace prefix, `u:` to `urn:hl7-org:v3`.

Then, this XPath,

```
//u:id[@root='1.2.643.100.3']/@extension
```

will return `03480134121`, as requested.

If you are unable to bind a namespace prefix, you can instead use this XPath,

```
//*[local-name() ='id' and @root='1.2.643.100.3']/@extension
```

which will also return `03480134121`, as requested.