# XPath to extract a portion of attribute

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm new to Xpath and I'm trying to figure out how to extract the attribute of the extension with the value of D000001602 as shown below.

```
<ClinDoc>
  <ComponentOf>
    <encompassingEncounter>
       <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.52.3" extension="D000001602"/>
       <effectiveTime>
          <low value="20140620135800"/>
          <high value="20140701140756"/>
       </effectiveTime>
    </encompassingEncounter>
  </componentOf>
 </ClinDoc>
```

I am using an online extractor with the following code but I can't seem to get it to work:

/clindoc/componentof/encompassingEncounter/id[@root=2.16.840.1.113883.3.529.3]/@extension

//id[@root=2.16.840.1.113883.3.529.3]/@extension

Thanks much!

Comment: ***What's going on here?***  First, this question is the same as [**one I answered yesterday by a different user**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335844/how-get-attribute-content-by-another-attribute-value-with-xpath).  Are you in the same class as @Usm, or are you the same person, or what?  Second, this question orginally referenced an [**image**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oMTnE.jpg), and when I asked that you include text, you critically dropped a default namespace, so no mater what anyone answers here, you probably won't get an answer that works.

Comment: First, I am not the same person you are referring to that asked the same question yesterday. I'm not in a class and I'm just trying to discover how to extract the info from the xml file that our company is receiving to be able to upload it properly in one of our systems. Also, I tried uploading an image but when I checked it, it failed to show that's why I decided to put the code itself. Now is the code I added the same image as @Usm posted?

Comment: I am not wasting my time as I tried to search for something before I posted my question and @Usm post didn't appear in my search results. JLRishe was kind enough to answer my question. And just so you know, there are a lot of different types of ClinicalDocument out there in case you don't know. Usm question and mine is SIMILAR but NOT duplicate. In computer world, similar is not the same as duplicate!

Comment: it could be that this type of xml is widely adopted .. a pure coincidence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to match `root` with the string value *2.16.840.1.113883.3.52.3*, which means you need to represent it as a string literal in the XPath.

Also, node names are case sensitive:

```
/ClinDoc/Componentof/encompassingEncounter/id[@root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.529.3"]/@extension
```

Comment: You might not want to put much time into this.  I'll explain in a comment on the question shortly...